# Spurious solutions when using NSolve on a simplified equation

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

I am solving an equation that should have only one solution in $[0,1]$, and as shown below, `equ2` is a simplified version of `equ1` using `FullSimplify`.

The problem is:

1. When I use `NSolve` on `equ1`, I get the right solution.
2. When I use `NSolve` on `equ2`, I get many spurious solutions, but there is a right one among them. However, when I put these wrong solutions into `equ2`, the result isn't even close to 0.
3. When I use `Solve` on `equ2`, I can get the right solution using `N`.

Does anyone have any explanation or suggestions for this behaviour?

```
ClearAll[equ1, equ2, n, A, L, v, x, r, b];

equ1[n_, A_, L_, v_, r_] = 
  v*(Sum[Binomial[n - 1, i - 1]*v^(n - i)*(1 - v)^(i - 1)*
        L/(n - i + 1), {i, n - L}] + 
      Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - L - 1 + i]*
        v^(L - i)*(1 - v)^(n - 1 - L + i), {i, L}]) - (v - r)*
    Sum[Binomial[n - 1, i - 1]*v^(n - i)*(1 - v)^(i - 1), {i, A}];
equ2[n_, A_, L_, v_, r_] := (L (1/v)^n v^n)/
   n + ((1 - v)^
    A v^(-A + n) (-r + v) Binomial[-1 + n, -A + n] Hypergeometric2F1[
     1, 1 - A, 1 - A + n, v/(-1 + v)])/(-1 + 
    v) - (1 - v)^(-1 - L + n) (-1 + v) v^
    L Binomial[-1 + n, -L + n] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - L, 
     1 - L + n, (-1 + v)/v] - (1 - v)^(-L + n) v^
    L Binomial[-1 + n, -L + n] Hypergeometric2F1[1, -L, 
     1 - L + n, (-1 + v)/v];

NSolve[equ1[1000, 30, 30, v, 0] == 0  && 0 < v < 1]
(* 1 correct solution *)

NSolve[equ2[1000, 30, 30, v, 0] == 0 && 0 < v < 1]
(* 1 correct + 102 spurious solutions *)

Solve[equ2[1000, 30, 30, v, 0] == 0 && 0 < v < 1] // N
(* 1 correct solution *)
```

Comment: MMA version 13.3 If I try FullSimplify[equ1] I do net get equ2

Comment: @DanielHuber Sorry, I didn't mentioned that I applied a math change to one term in equ1 because it isn't the point, but it does make FullSimplify[equ1] and equ2 look similar but not the same, however they are equivalent in mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Solve` will find an *exact* result using various algebraic methods – the result is one `Root` object, which you then numerically evaluate with `N[]`.

`NSolve` on the other hand is a *numeric solver* which – as all of them – is sensitive to numerical errors. They may accumulate and affect the computation differently for different symbolic representations of the same function (ie. `equ1` and `equ2`).

Increasing `WorkingPrecision` will correctly return just one solution even for `equ2`.

```
NSolve[equ2[1000, 30, 30, v, 0] == 0 && 0 < v < 1, WorkingPrecision -> 75]
(* {{v -> 0.959217483252 }} *)
```